# Cartographic Representations Load Rather Than Feature Symbology

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, symbology, representation

We use ArcSDE to allow multiple users (both in my office and elsewhere) to access feature classes that my office maintains. We also use cartographic representations for many of our feature classes.

For some reason, those feature classes which have cartographic representations will always load the representation as the default symbolization when they're imported into ArcMap (rather than feature symbology).

This is a problem for GIS users outside our office. When they bring in our feature classes without using a layer file, they see our representations, which are not an accurate representation of the spatial location of the data, rather than the feature symbology. This can throw them off.

Is there any way to make the features load with default symbology rather than with their representations?

Comment: I don't know the answer but I think the question is whether representations in a feature class can be stored as invisible/hidden by default so that when added to a map they are NOT seen without that setting being modified.  I've looked for the answer here: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Erasing_and_hiding_feature_representations/008t0000005q000000/

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Experimenting with the options for hiding a representation, the feature class still loads with the representation as the default symbology, it's just hidden. So nothing appears on the map, basically.

This may be useful in the sense that incorrect geometry can't be shown, but it still doesn't solve the root problem - the representation is still the default symbology.

Comment: As a suggestion it may be worth making an ArcGIS Forum posting to see if anyone there has any alternative ideas, otherwise you may want to consider posting an ArcGIS Idea for the behaviour you seek. (I'll vote for it).

Comment: Which version of ArcGIS for Desktop with the ArcSDE component from which version of ArcGIS for Server are you seeing this in?  I'm thinking about knocking up a test using ArcGIS 10.2 with a file geodatabase to see if I can reproduce this but will save the effort if the issue is no longer there for you.